# Adding a fade-in effect to an image just loaded using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a main image which can be changed to one of five different images by the user clicking on a link. In this case, either link 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' or 'five'.

So clicking the link 'three' will change the main image to display the 3rd image.

This is all working correctly, but I am looking for the images to fade in rather than appear instantly. Is this possible with a quick modifications of the code below?

Many thanks in advance,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Image Change Demo</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeIt(objName)
{
//The image object accessed through its id we mentioned in the DIV block which is going to be visible currently
var obj = document.getElementById(objName);

//An array that hold the IDs of images that we mentioned in their DIV blocks
var objId = new Array();

//Storing the image IDs into the array starts here
objId[0] = "image1";
objId[1] = "image2";
objId[2] = "image3";
objId[3] = "image4";
objId[4] = "image5";
//Storing the image IDs into the array ends here

//A counter variable going to use for iteration
var i;

//A variable that can hold all the other object references other than the object which is going to be visible
var tempObj;

//The following loop does the display of a single image based on its ID. The image whose ID we passed into this function will be the
//only image that is displayed rest of the images will be hidden based on their IDs and that part has been handled by the else part
//of the if statement within this loop.
for(i=0;i<objId.length;i++)
{
    if(objName == objId[i])
    {
        obj.style.display = "block";
        rotate.nu=i;
    }
    else
    {
        tempObj = document.getElementById(objId[i]);
        tempObj.style.display = "none";
    }
}
return;
}

function rotate()
{

//An array that hold the IDs of images that we mentioned in their DIV blocks
var objId = new Array();

//Storing the image IDs into the array starts here
objId[0] = "image1";
objId[1] = "image2";
objId[2] = "image3";
objId[3] = "image4";
objId[4] = "image5";
rotate.nu=rotate.nu||0;
document.getElementById(objId[rotate.nu]).style.display = "none";
rotate.nu=++rotate.nu%objId.length;
document.getElementById(objId[rotate.nu]).style.display = "block";
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="image1" onmouseup="rotate();" >
<img src="dimming/1.jpg" border="0" alt="one" />
</div>

<div id="image2" style="display:none" onmouseup="rotate();">
<img src="dimming/2.jpg" border="0" alt="two" />
</div>

<div id="image3" style="display:none" onmouseup="rotate();">
<img src="dimming/C.jpg" border="0" alt="three" />
</div>

<div id="image4" style="display:none" onmouseup="rotate();">
<img src="dimming/D.jpg" border="0" alt="four" />
</div>

<div id="image5" style="display:none" onmouseup="rotate();">
<img src="dimming/E.jpg" border="0" alt="five" />
</div>
<br><br>
<a id="one" href="#" onclick="changeIt('image1');">one</a>
<a id="two" href="#" onclick="changeIt('image2');">two</a>
<a id="three" href="#" onclick="changeIt('image3');">three</a>
<a id="four" href="#" onclick="changeIt('image4');">four</a>
<a id="five" href="#" onclick="changeIt('image5');">five</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any jquery above. Is there a reason this is tagged with jQuery? Note, current answers require jquery.

Comment: If it can be achieved with jQuery then I am open to suggestions. Thanks for your help ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you looking for the easy way, you might use jQuery framework. Usage like this:

```
$('.image').fadeIn(1000)
```

Comment: Hi Johnny, where would that go in the example above? Or would I need to rewrite the whole thing?